# Диалог Сохранить как

Tags: php, ajax, файлы, header, save

Всем привет.
У меня в проекте все управляется через Ajax, ответ в виде массива перебираю и отрабатываю

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: ds,
      complete: function(resp) {
        var dopParams = resp.responseJSON.dop; //тут массив из инструкций JQ
          for (let i = 0; i < dopParams.length; i++) {
          eval(dopParams[i]);
        }
  }
  });
```

В РНР файле формирую JQ инструкции наподобие

```
$dop[] = "$('#my-element').html('test')"; 
return $dop;
```

Все отрабатывается корректно, даже заполнение data-table. Потребовалось в ответ на действие пользователя сгенерить некий текстовый/бинарный файл и предложить пользователю выбрать место для сохранения. На тестовой страничке без Ajax все работает:

```
$data = file_get_content('/path/to/file');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="NewFileName.txt"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); // Для IE
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
```

А если логику перенести в проект сайта, вызов которой осущеcтвляется через Ajax, то возврат этих строк вызывает ошибку:

```
dop[0] = "header(\"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\\\"NewFileName.txt\\\"\")" //собственно сама строка
Ошибка - Uncaught ReferenceError: header is not defined // в строке где (eval(dop[0]))
```

как "пропустить" header ?

Answer (score 0):

В результате решил проблему:

1. Пользователь нажимает кнопку "Сохранить", через Ajax от браузера до сервера передается параметр, например 'delo'='save-file'.
2. На сервере по этому параметру вызывается соответствующая функция, в которой

- считывается подготовленный ранее файл,
- создается массив в котором построчно содержится содержимое файла (он у меня с десяток- другой строк, не экспериментировал с сотнями строк)
- в Ajax возвращается заполненный массив: 1 элемент имя файла [name], 2 элемент - вложенный массив [soder]

3. На браузере путем внутренних манипуляций (создание и нажимание ссылки) создается Blob и сохраняется. Для этого используется функция:

> ```
> function saveToPC(arr){
>   let str ="";
>   let soder = arr['soder'];
>   let name = arr['name'];
>   soder.forEach(function(entry) {
>     str += entry;
>   });
>   let blob = new Blob([str], {type: "text/plain"});
>   let link = document.createElement("a");
>   link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
>   link.setAttribute("download", name);
>   link.click();
> }
> ```

Может кому-то пригодится, расписывал подробно.